# Footnote within a Figure environment below caption

Tags: floats, captions, footnotes

I have a figure consisting a minipage with an enumerated list of text. One of those enumerated text has a footnote  as shown in the example below.  The problem is that the footnote appears above the caption of the figure.

```
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \begin{enumerate}
          \item Test item\footnote{test footnote text.}
      \end{enumerate}
   \end{minipage}
   \caption{test caption}
\end{figure}
```

Is there any way to put the footnote below the caption?

Comment: Why is this used as `figure` environment at all? The `footnote` in minipage is emitted right after the end of `minipage`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It just seemed a slightly more clear way to explain something in my text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put  the`\caption`  after the enumerate so the footnote is inserted at the end of the minipage below the caption.

Comment: While technically correct, the question remains: Why is that a `figure` environment?!

Comment: @Skillmon why not?

Comment: @Skillmon It just seemed a slightly more clear way to explain something in my text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks David. Your suggestion did the trick.